# My target SDK version is 25 but Google Play says app only supports 4.1-4.4 devices?

Tags: android, sdk, google-play

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 25
buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.abc.ege"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 25
    versionCode 3
    versionName "1.1.3"
    vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
}
```

Although my target sdk version is 25, when I upload the apk to play store, it says "not compatible with devices with android version 4.4 and over, where is the problem?

edit: app works fine on emulators and there is no hardware access in manifest file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the issue. Looks like an external library's android manifest file maxSDK is set to 19.

Comment: Then what's the solution to resolve this issue? Thanks @Egek92.

Comment: @RUTURAJRaval not using an old, unreliable 3rd party library is the solution. I deleted that library from my project.

Comment: Great let me try this solution too.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should lowerize `targetSdkVersion` to 24, as 25 (7.1) is not released yet.

Comment: My bad, can you explain the difference between compileSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion please?

Comment: "compileSdkVersion specifies the Android API level Gradle should use to compile your app. This means your app can use the API features included in this API level and lower."
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/index.html