# My Android Studio app only works for API's 23 and above

Tags: android, api, android-studio, sdk

I need to build an app for API min sdk version 16, it builds successfully but it refuses to work for API's below 23. The messages reads "Unfortunately, AppName has stopped" but works perfectly for API 23 and above

The error in the logcat I got when running the app in the emulator API 16

```
12-20 13:55:27.942    2612-2612/com.rhmfx.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.rhmfx.myapplication/com.rhmfx.myapplication.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020052
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/abc_vector_test.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020052
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1923)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:659)
            at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:355)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:201)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:189)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:710)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:194)
            at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:81)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:129)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:152)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:29)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:53)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:204)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:184)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:518)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:70)
            at com.rhmfx.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #17: invalid drawable tag vector
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:877)
            at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:818)
            at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1920)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:659)
            at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:355)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:201)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:189)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.checkVectorDrawableSetup(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:710)
            at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:194)
            at android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getDrawableIfKnown(TintTypedArray.java:81)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:129)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:152)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV11.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV11.java:29)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV14.<init>(AppCompatDelegateImplV14.java:53)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:204)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegate.create(AppCompatDelegate.java:184)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.getDelegate(AppCompatActivity.java:518)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:70)
            at com.rhmfx.myapplication.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:36)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

In my build.gradle file the settings are

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rhmfx.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
}
```

Please help me to fix the errors shown so I can run the app for API's 16 and above. Thanks

Comment: remove this drawable `abc_vector_test.xml` use a svg image or png image instead of this

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34417843/how-to-use-vector-drawables-in-android-api-lower-21

Comment: This is not a duplicate just for the "Resources$NotFoundException:" message. @Nilu

Answer (score 0):

3rd party libraries with Max Api levels may cause this error. Please see this question.

[My target SDK version is 25 but Google Play says app only supports 4.1-4.4 devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40941086/my-target-sdk-version-is-25-but-google-play-says-app-only-supports-4-1-4-4-devic)

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is:

> Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line
>   17: invalid drawable tag vector

You must specify the vector drawables support :

```
 vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
```

add into your `build.gradle` file, `defaultConfig`  section:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rhmfx.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true  
    }
```